# Apache vhost configuration for ServerAlias getting default

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, serveralias

Given this configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName    www.example.net
        ServerAlias   testy.example.net
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName    www.example.org
        ServerAlias   new.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Requests for www.* are served as I expect, the page(s) for the .net and .org sites are delivered.

However requests for the ServerAliases, new.example.org and testy.example.net, are fufilled from default.example.com

This is on Apache 2.2.22

/usr/sbin/apache2 -f  -S only shows *default* servers ... so digging, digging further

Comment: Only difference with my config is that i've got listen 0.0.0.0:80
-S shows every servername vhost

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
ServerName    example.net
ServerAlias   *.example.net
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to serverfault. Your response is not enough to count as an answer, these kind of proposals can merely be posted as a comment. Please make your reply more substantial and give an explanation why the proposed idea might work.

Comment: I guess I can't leave comments to other people's questions or answers since you need 50 points to leave comments. Anyways this reputation things are not for me already. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

OFM

My example should have read:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    www.example.net
    ServerAlias   testy.example.net. otherhost.example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

My bind habit, on that one host, of specifying a FQDN with a terminating dot in this context yields a non-parsable name.

Nothing to see here, move along now.